# Autoincrement of identity errors with duplicate primary key even after delete all rows, Trunc datatable and DBCC reseed

Tags: sql-server, database

SQL Server. Initial problem was that autoincrement value of the identity primary key reached 2147483647. Accordingly, I deleted all of the table rows (it just holds temporary work values) and instructed the DBA to run

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (TableName, RESEED, 1);
```

That seemed to work and my tried and true application which works with the table was able to fill the table with about 19,300 rows before hitting an error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key in object

I shifted to a dev server, ran the `DBCC CHECKIDENT RESET` command. The same program errored adding rows when it hit 2.   I am able to manually insert rows using SSMS not programmatically. The program's insert command does not reference the primary key column.

I've tried deleting all rows, reseeding to 0, running the trunc command but the programmatic insert still somehow encounters the same primary key value which SQL Server insists exists even though it doesn't.

Ok, I admit that it sounds like an application program but why would I encounter primary key violation in the same table that has no records.

The corrected refactored insert code reads:  The refactored insert query reads:

```
INSERT INTO [Ur_Imported_CourseEnroll] ([source], [role],[row_status], [external_course_key], [notes],[registration_status_refid], [snapshotGuid], [external_person_key])    
VALUES ('urstudent', 'Student', 'ENABLED', 'COURSE_SECTION-3-102090', 'source file: StudEnroll_URSTUDENT', 'COMPLETED', 'c38cb97928a6466395e92af996e91908', '31730266')
```

An earlier copy did include an errant comma (copy and paste error).

There are no triggers or foreign keys. There are default values and the primary key constraint.

The cleansed application's connection string reads:

```
Data Source=SERVERNAME.edu;Initial Catalog=BbLmDataImports;User ID=DBUSER;Password=DBPASSWORD" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

The full error message reads:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Ur_Imported_CourseEnroll'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Ur_Imported_CourseEnroll'. The duplicate key value is (10). The statement has been terminated.

The referenced key value does increment if I add a row through SQL Server Management Studio. So I am certain that the application is addressing the same server, database and table as the SQL Server Management Studio.

I realized that the involved table is very "standalone" with no foreign data keys or triggers. So I tried an experiment and created a new table using a modified "create" script from SQL Server Management Studio. I then changed the app code to reference the new table name.   Everything is working. Not a win because I'm unsure what was happening but I'll settle for this draw.

Comment: Please post full error message and trace from application. It can be inserting additional tables using this identity as a part of a key.

Comment: What actual SQL commands is the application running?

Comment: The table's primary key column is PK1.     The attempted insert command  is "INSERT INTO [Ur_Imported_CourseEnroll] ([source],[role],[row_status],[external_course_key],[notes],[registration_status_refid],[snapshotGuid],[external_person_key]) VALUES (@source,@role,@row_status,@external_course_key,@notes,@registration_status_refid,@snapshotGuid,@external_person_key)"

Comment: The full error message is {"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Ur_Imported_CourseEnroll'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Ur_Imported_CourseEnroll'. The duplicate key value is (10)." & vbCrLf & "The statement has been terminated."}

Comment: The actual values being inserted are   ["@source"] "urstudent" 
  ["@role"] "Student" 
  ["@row_status"] "ENABLED" 
  ["@external_course_key"] "COURSE_SECTION-3-102090" 
  ["@notes"] "source file: StudEnroll_URSTUDENT" 
  ["@registration_status_refid"] "COMPLETED" 
  ["@snapshotGuid"] "c38cb97928a6466395e92af996e91908" 
  ["@external_person_key"] "31730266"

Comment: Please do [edit] any additional information directly into your question.

Comment: I've refactored the insert command to be more straightforward.   I can run it in SQL Server manager without issue.    Of course, I've had "bugs" before and don't mind owning up if this is one.   But I don't understand why it's appearing after 10 years of operation after reseeding the primary key column.

Comment: The refactored insert query reads:  INSERT INTO [Ur_Imported_CourseEnroll] ([source],[role],[row_status],[external_course_key],[notes],[registration_status_refid],[snapshotGuid],[external_person_key]) VALUES (
, 'urstudent'
, 'Student'
, 'ENABLED'
, 'COURSE_SECTION-3-102090'
, 'source file: StudEnroll_URSTUDENT'
, 'COMPLETED'
, 'c38cb97928a6466395e92af996e91908'
, '31730266'
)

Comment: @AaronBertrand No triggers.   There are constraints

Comment: The Create Table SQL reads:

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Ur_Imported_CourseEnroll](
[External_Course_Key] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[External_Person_key] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Role] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
[Row_status] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
[notes] [varchar](8000) NOT NULL,
[Source] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
[SnapshotGuid] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[dateCreated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[pk1] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[AutomatedProcess] [bit] NOT NULL,
[Registration_Status_RefID] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,

Comment: CONSTRAINT [PK_Ur_Imported_CourseEnroll] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
[pk1] ASC
 [pk1] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Ur_Imported_CourseEnroll] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__Ur_Import__Exter__7C8480AE]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [External_Course_Key]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Ur_Imported_CourseEnroll] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__Ur_Import__Exter__7D78A4E7]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [External_Person_key]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Ur_Imported_CourseEnroll] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__Ur_Importe__Role__7E6CC920]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [Role]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Ur_Imported_CourseEnroll] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__Ur_Import__Row_s__7F60ED59]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [Row_status]

Comment: ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Ur_Imported_CourseEnroll] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__Ur_Import__notes__00551192]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [notes]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Ur_Imported_CourseEnroll] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__Ur_Import__Sourc__014935CB]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [Source]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Ur_Imported_CourseEnroll] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__Ur_Import__Snaps__023D5A04]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [SnapshotGuid]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Ur_Imported_CourseEnroll] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__Ur_Import__dateC__03317E3D]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [dateCreated]

Comment: ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Ur_Imported_CourseEnroll] ADD  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [AutomatedProcess]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Ur_Imported_CourseEnroll] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Ur_Imported_CourseEnroll_Registration_Status_RefID]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [Registration_Status_RefID]

Comment: Does your application use a connection string that uses AttachDbFileName or User Instances? Are you absolutely 100% positive the application and your query window are connecting to the same database on the same instance? Please stop adding big chunks of code to comments - add this info to your question. And correct whatever is missing from your insert (a leading comma inside values is invalid syntax).

Comment: @AaronBertrand  I apologize for my rudeness and bad posting habits.   See description for answers to your questions

Comment: Oh I never suggested you were being rude. But if we don’t tell you, you can never know. If you look at the comment thread you should recognize that those chunks of code are completely unreadable, but even if they were more readable, this is info that belongs in the question, not as an afterthought / trailing string of random text.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the involved table is very "standalone" with no foreign data keys or triggers.   So I tried an experiment and created a new table using a modified "create" script from SQL Server Manager.  I then changed the app code to reference the new table name.   Everything is working.  Not a win because I'm unsure what was happening but I'll settle for this draw.

Comment: This is certainly strange syntax for definition of a PK: `CONSTRAINT [PK_Ur_Imported_CourseEnroll] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ( [pk1] ASC [pk1] ASC )` Why does `pk1` appear twice here?